# Is the default return type in C++11 long?

Tags: c++, c++11, clion

I'm using **CLion 2017.2.3** and there is an error by its Intellisense saying `Return type of function 'func' differs...` (**Image attached below**). Isn't the default return type in `C++` `int`? And why is the IDE showing it as an error? Is it a bug?

**EDIT: It compiles and runs fine(without any flags, doesn't with them)**

[image]

Comment: There is no default return type. Provide one yourself. And of course, if you really want to know what the language thinks, run your compiler on it and check the warning.

Comment: It's not the return statement, it's that you forgot to write `int` before the function definition

Comment: This is a good question. I wonder why the downvotes.

Comment: Just add `int` on line 13 before `func()`

Comment: It's most likely a CLion artifact; there is no default return type in C++. Intellisenses often get confused by broken code. The actual error is that you didn't provide a return type on the definition.

Comment: There are no "default return types" (aka implicit `int`) in C++.

Comment: @Elazar Because it's not useful.

Comment: @BaummitAugen what? This is a very useful question. C has default return type, CLion claims that C++ does too. Puzzling indeed.

Comment: Thanks @molbdnilo. I wonder whether it's because the reason of it being an error it's messing up with intellisense?

Comment: @Elazar The not useful part, IMO, is assuming a generic IDE knows more about what the language does or does not allow than simply asking the letter of the language, i.e. cppreference or the Standard or any other of various available resources.

Comment: _"EDIT: It compiles and runs fine."_ Now configure your compiler to expect valid Standard C++, turn on all errors and warnings, and see what happens.

Comment: @Elazar So what's useful about that question? Finding out why some IDE emits the wrong diagnostic for some obvious mistake?

Comment: @BaummitAugen The answer "this diagnostics is wrong" is very good answer to this good question. What's obvious to you is (obviously) not obvious to the OP, which seems to be more knowledgeable than many C++ users that might read this question.

Comment: @Elazar - RE: *" C has default return type"* that's not true. It wasn't true since 1999.

Comment: @Elazar It's obvious to anyone who ever read any part of any C++ book or tutorial. Writing C++ based on guessing and then being surprised about the result is no constructive, as is this question.

Comment: @BaummitAugen I was being specific about CLion there(and that's why I tagged it). And I knew it wasn't nice(for a lack of better word) to not put a return type. Just that the warning was a bit weird.

Comment: Might be stating the obvious here, but just for fun trivia `0` is a `int` literal, so in theory if you were to set the return type to `auto`, an `int` would always be returned.

Comment: @underscore_d the edit was to indicate that the intellisense was wrong about it being an error. That's all!

Comment: @Bateman No, it **is** an error, at least if you're using a compiler in a conforming mode, as I said.

Comment: @underscore_d I meant the "Return type of function 'func' differs..." part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no default return type in standard C++.

The IDE / compiler might be reusing the the same code that it is using for analyzing C89 definitions. I have no idea why is it `long`.

Answer (score 0):

This seems as though it's a compiler or IDE setting. The return type is set to int, and your value is within the range of a standard int, so it should implicitly convert. I suspect it is the IDE, not the compiler, since you've stated that it does compile and run successfully. Check your settings, perhaps reset them to default, and try to write the same code in a new project/file.

Comment: So, what was your answer to the question of whether C++11 has a default return type?

Comment: It was more intended as an extension of the other answer, since they'd see both.